# How to pass Headers in rest assured test in java

Tags: java, rest-assured, web-api-testing

I am new to rest assured,I am trying to do a very basic test of checking the response body and status.I am passing the headers as required in this API call
but when I run the test I am getting 401 unauthorized message instead of showing me the result in response body.when I am running the same API using Postman then its working fine

Below is the code that I have tried but its not working
I am including the sample url and headers value as cant share real ones

```
package test;

import org.testng.Assert;
import org.testng.annotations.Test;

import io.restassured.RestAssured;
import io.restassured.http.Method;
import io.restassured.response.Response;
import io.restassured.specification.RequestSpecification;

public class SimpleGetTest {

    @Test
    public void GetWeatherDetails() {

        RestAssured.baseURI = "https://test.com";


        RequestSpecification httpRequest = RestAssured.given();

        Response response = httpRequest.given().header("Content-Type", "application/json").given()
                .header("x-api-key", "123456").
                request(Method.GET, "/hello");

        System.out.println("Response sent =>  " + response);


        String responseBody = response.getBody().asString();
        System.out.println("Response Body is =>  " + responseBody);


        int statusCode = response.getStatusCode();
        System.out.println("Actual Status Code is : " + statusCode);

        Assert.assertEquals(statusCode, 200,
                "BUG : Status code is coming as different");
        System.out.println("Expected : Status code coming correct");

    }
}
```

below is the console message that I am getting,in which its showing 401

Response sent =>  io.restassured.internal.RestAssuredResponseImpl@18cebaa5
Response Body is =>  "message":"UNAUTHORIZED_ACCESS","code":"401","data":null}
Actual Status Code is : 200
Expected : Status code coming correct
PASSED: GetWeatherDetails

Answer (score 0):

I ran your exact test on my eclipse and it worked as expected. Here's the output:

```
[RemoteTestNG] detected TestNG version 6.14.3
Response sent =>  io.restassured.internal.RestAssuredResponseImpl@21526f6c
Response Body is =>  <!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/strict.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1">
<meta http-equiv="Content-Script-Type" content="text/javascript">
<script type="text/javascript">
function getCookie(c_name) { // Local function for getting a cookie value
    if (document.cookie.length > 0) {
        c_start = document.cookie.indexOf(c_name + "=");
        if (c_start!=-1) {
        c_start=c_start + c_name.length + 1;
        c_end=document.cookie.indexOf(";", c_start);

        if (c_end==-1) 
            c_end = document.cookie.length;

        return unescape(document.cookie.substring(c_start,c_end));
        }
    }
    return "";
}
function setCookie(c_name, value, expiredays) { // Local function for setting a value of a cookie
    var exdate = new Date();
    exdate.setDate(exdate.getDate()+expiredays);
    document.cookie = c_name + "=" + escape(value) + ((expiredays==null) ? "" : ";expires=" + exdate.toGMTString()) + ";path=/";
}
function getHostUri() {
    var loc = document.location;
    return loc.toString();
}
setCookie('YPF8827340282Jdskjhfiw_928937459182JAX666', '86.172.130.153', 10);
try {  
    location.reload(true);  
} catch (err1) {  
    try {  
        location.reload();  
    } catch (err2) {  
        location.href = getHostUri();  
    }  
}
</script>
</head>
<body>
<noscript>This site requires JavaScript and Cookies to be enabled. Please change your browser settings or upgrade your browser.</noscript>
</body>
</html>

Actual Status Code is : 200
Expected : Status code coming correct
PASSED: GetWeatherDetails

===============================================
    Default test
    Tests run: 1, Failures: 0, Skips: 0
===============================================


===============================================
Default suite
Total tests run: 1, Failures: 0, Skips: 0
===============================================
```

Make sure you have the right dependencies and check with the TestNG version you are using.

Answer (score 0):

**try below code will work**

Map headers = new HashMap<>(); headers.put("Auth-Service-Id", "my-app"); headers.put("Auth-Identifier", "blaBlaBlabla");

Response response = RestAssured.given(this.requestSpecification) .headers(headers) .when() .get("http=://xyz.com");

Answer (score 0):

With **io.rest-assured:rest-assured:4.2.1** dependency below code can be acheived.

```
RequestSpecification httpRequest = RestAssured.given();
Response response = httpRequest
                   .contentType("application/json")
                   .header("x-api-key", "123456")
                   .request(Method.GET, "/hello");
```

(OR)
Incase if you need to pass other custom headers below code will help

**EG:**

```
Header languageHeader = new Header("Accept-Language", en);
Header keytHeader = new Header("x-api-key", "123456");
Header secretHeader = new Header("x-api-secret", "123456");
Headers headers = new Headers(languageHeader, keytHeader, secretHeader);

Response response = RestAssured.given()
                   .contentType("application/json")
                   .headers(headers)
                   .request(Method.GET, "/hello");
```